# Error en query MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Cuando trato de correr, el siguiente query no me arroja nada. alguien podria asesorarme, Gracias.

```
SELECT * FROM bd.tabla WHERE interv='15seg' 
    IF(interv='15seg' 
    AND fecha_hora='2016-08-02 00:00:00' 
    AND fecha_hora >= '2016-08-18 23:59:59')
    SET hora between '00:00:00' and '00:00:00' 
    ELSE (interv='5HZ,15seg' 
    AND and fecha_hora >= '2016-08-02 00:00:00' 
    AND fecha_hora <= '2016-08-18 23:59:59' 
    and estacion in ('est1','est2','est3') 
and hora between '00:00:00' and '03:59:59')
```

Comment: Creo que necesitamos ver los datos de tu tabla (algunos).

Comment: ¿Qué error te arroja? ¿O simplemente no te arroja nada?

Comment: Me gustaría añadir que tienes un doble `and` en la 3 línea por debajo, no debería funcionar la consulta así =P

Answer (score 8):

Esto

```
AND fecha_hora='2016-08-02 00:00:00' 
AND fecha_hora >= '2016-08-18 23:59:59')
```

suenan de entrada dos `AND` incompatibles entre sí porque dice al sistema de buscar dos rangos de fechas disociados con un `AND`, cosa que jamás sucedera, por lo tanto no regresa nada.

Quizas si lo modificas en

```
AND fecha_hora>='2016-08-02 00:00:00' 
AND fecha_hora <= '2016-08-18 23:59:59')
```

suena más lógico.

Quizás hay más cosas sobre el contenido de la tabla misma, pero esto salta a los ojos inmediatamente.

Answer (score 5):

Si lo que necesitas es buscar entre fechas, lo mejor es que uses [`between`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between).

Es más fácil de leer y el sistema sabrá lo que tiene que hacer, pues es una función.

---

#### Ejemplo

```sql
WHERE
.
.
AND

fecha_hora BETWEEN '2016-08-02 00:00:00' AND '2016-08-18 23:59:59'
.
.
```

Answer (score 2):

Prueba a poner las fechas con un `BETWEEN`

```
SELECT * FROM bd.tabla WHERE interv='15seg' 
    IF(interv='15seg' 
    AND fecha_hora BETWEEN '2016-08-02 00:00:00' 
    AND '2016-08-18 23:59:59')
    SET hora between '00:00:00' and '00:00:00' 
    ELSE (interv='5HZ,15seg' 
    AND fecha_hora BETWEEN '2016-08-02 00:00:00' 
    AND '2016-08-18 23:59:59' 
    and estacion in ('est1','est2','est3') 
and hora between '00:00:00' and '03:59:59')
```

`BETWEEN` es un operador muy útil a utilizar dentro de la claúsula WHERE, para especificar un rango de valores inclusivos. Se utiliza normalmente con fechas pero también se puede usar con strings y con números.